# Suppress Section conditionally based on item in details

Tags: crystal-reports

Lets just say i have this data in my details

1. Item One
2. Item Two
3. Item Three
4. Item Four
5. Item Five

I want to suppress (Hidden) "Footer Section C" if there is "Item Three" in the "Detail Section".

Is there any good trick to do that ?. I have tried making a formula and place it inside details section and then pass the value into parameter field but still has no result.

I hope you can help me here. thanks

**Note:**

What i have been doing.

create 2 formula field one named january1 and the other one named janparameter

add formula field "january1" inside the detail section with this script inside it

```
WhileReadingRecords;
if {MyTable.MyItem} = "Item Three"  then
{@janparameter} = "1"
else
{@janparameter} = "0"
```

and in "Footer Section C" in "Suppress (No Drill Down)" i put down this script

```
{@janparameter} = "0"
```

mean that if {@janparameter} values is equal "0" then "Footer Section C" will be Suppressed. but this is not working at all for me. I hope there is someone who can solve this mistery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code inside the suppression-formula of the details-section:

```
{MyTable.Item} = "Item Three"
```

`{MyTable.Item}` should be replaced with the appropriate field of your database-table.

Above is the short version of:

```
If {MyTable.Item} = "Item Three" Then True Else False
```

Which means, if the item is `"Item Three"` then suppress the section else show the section.

### EDIT 1:

As the goal is to suppress the page footer instead of the detail section, above solution does not work.

A parameter can not be used like it is a variable. Furthermore `{@janparameter}` is a formula not a parameter. Parameters start with a question mark `?` not with a `@`.

What the `january1`-formula currently does is returning `True` on the appropriate detail if the value of `{MyTable.MyItem}` is "Item Three" and the value of `@janparameter` is `1`. If not, then `False` is returned.

To achieve what you want you can use a variable.

Replace the code of the `@january1`-formula with the following:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
booleanVar ItemThreeFound;
If {MyTable.MyItem} = "Item Three" Then ItemThreeFound := True;
```

...and in the suppression-formula of "Footer Section C" put the following:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
booleanVar ItemThreeFound;
```

### EDIT 2:

To get the opposite behavior, just add `Not`:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Not booleanVar ItemThreeFound;
```

Comment: you mean using the database field as a parameter ? is that really all right ? i mean i am still newbie but i though we can't change database field value except its format, so i'm using Parameter Field all this time. for example 

`    if right({Invoice.ItemCode},7) = "2305580"  then
{@janparameter} = "1" `


but still, when i use @janparameter inside suppress section in the section i want to hide. it still show up even if there is "Item Three"

Comment: The value will not be changed with this formula. It will just be compared to the string "Item Three" and if it's equal then the section will be suppressed. There's no need for a parameter-field at all.

Comment: oh I'm sorry if my question is not detail, what i want to suppress is not the "detail section" but "footer section c". is the same formula will be working too if i put it inside the suppress formula ?

Comment: No it won't work like this. Please edit your question and add the **detailed** requirements.

Comment: okay , just edited the question. i hope you can help me again.

Comment: Cool its work, but what if i want it the opposite ? the Section Footer C will be always suppressed except if there is an Item Three ?

Comment: I have tried 

WhilePrintingRecords;
booleanVar ItemThreeFound :=false;

but still no result at all